# How do I test a void method that just creates a client and sends a message?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, azureservicebus

I am new to testing and I have a method which I do not know how to test with mockito.  I tested methods which have return calls in the past, but this is the first time I have tried to write a test for this.  I am not even sure what I need to test in the below method other than making sure the send method gets called.

```
    private void sendMsg(Message msg, String connectionString, String qName) throws InterruptedException, ServiceBusException {

        QueueClient client= new QueueClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, qName),
                ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
        client.send(msg);
        client.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should write a function which verifies the client was created as expected (by connecting to the DB, or any other storage you're using to save clients information), in this step you can also validate that client information was created and saved as expected (validate userName, password, and any other information you store).

For the Send Message function, you can validate that it gets called, that it doesn't produce any exception and if is an Email Message, you can also write a function that connects to an email address and validate the message gets received.

There are a lot of things you can test, but try to identify which ones are valuable for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Mockito, you can use Mockito verify: https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4

There is a great Baelding article here:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

You will likely need to mock other objects behavior, but this is the general idea for verifying that send was called once in Mockito:

```
@Mock
QueueClient client;
@Mock
Message msg;

@Test
public void testClienSendWasCalledOnce() {
    String connectionString;
    String qName;
    sendMsg(msg, connectionString, qName);

    verify(client, times(1)).send(msg);
}
```

If you are testing a final or static method PowerMock or EasyMock would work. There is a great Baelding article for PowerMock here:

https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock

Comment: why do I need to call client.send(msg)? if I am calling sendMsg in the line above, which will call client.send anyways.

Comment: Also this is for an Azure function app, so I get this error.  "org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.QueueClient
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class"

Comment: You don't need to call client.send(msg).  I copied your code into and editor to mockup my answer and accidentally left that line in.

Comment: Yeah Mockito can't mock final classes.  PowerMock works well for that though.  I've edited my answer.